# Laravel email Templates

Tags: php, laravel, email

**Hello I want to send e-mails rendered from templates that can be created / modifed by admin from a form (with placeholders).As in the example below and I want to send it to 100 users at the same time, I don't know how to do it, can you help?**

```
Hi { { name } }, 

email: {{email } }

phone: { { phone } }
```

*my controllers:*

```
    public function mailSend(Uye $uye, IcerikSablon $icerikSablon){
    $dil_id=$uye->ulke->dil_id;
    $icerikSablon->load(['translation'=>function($q)use ($dil_id){
        $q->where('dil_id',$dil_id);
    }]);
    $icerik_sablon_icerik=$icerikSablon->translation->icerik;


    $uye_name=$uye->name;
    $uye_phone=$uye->phone;
    $uye_mail=$uye->email;
    $icerik_sablon_icerik=  str_replace('{{name}}', $uye_name, $icerik_sablon_icerik;
    $icerik_sablon_icerik=str_replace('{{phone}}', $uye_phone, $icerik_sablon_icerik);
    $icerik_sablon_icerik=str_replace('{{email}}', $uye_mail, $icerik_sablon_icerik;

    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into the documentation for mailables and notifications for Laravel, it seems you are missing some basic setup. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail

From the docs:
`php artisan make:mail OrderShipped --markdown=emails.orders.shipped`

Then pass in the parameters you want to dynamically have in the `OrdersShipped` class constructor, and assign them as variables in your class. You can then reference these variables within your blade template.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail\Users;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrdersShipped extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * someVar
     *
     * @var $someVar;
     */
    protected $someVar;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param string $someVar
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($someVar)
    {
        $this->someVar = $someVar;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('test@test.com')
            ->subject('Password Reset Request')

            // Pass your vars in here using `with`

            ->with([
                'someVar' => $this->someVar,
            ])
            ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
    }
}
```

In `emails.order.shipped` blade you will be able to reference `{{ someVar }}`

Comment: I didn't ask any questions for mail sending. I just asked how to send templates for mail. For example, new registration template for new registration, template sending for order cancellation should all be done in a textarea.